# Can't ping two adhoc wireless lop tops (linux)

Tags: linux, networking, adhoc

I want to run an ad-hoc wireless on two lop tops that both of them have Linux OS. I use this for creating ad-hoc network.(I have stopped Network Manager before it)

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid test-adhoc channel 3
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

My ifconfig:

```
 ifconfig 
 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
           RX packets:25388 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:25388 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:3916018 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:3916018 (3.9 MB)

  vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
            inet addr:192.168.237.1  Bcast:192.168.237.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
            inet addr:172.16.62.1  Bcast:172.16.62.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:72:89:1b:19:76  
            inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::ae72:89ff:fe1b:1976/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:1543085 errors:0 dropped:27 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:19353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:183406489 (183.4 MB)  TX bytes:3741745 (3.7 MB)
```

And iwconfig

```
vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"test-adhoc"  
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Cell: A2:A3:E3:9B:6A:FA   
          Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.
```

IP for first Lop top is <192.168.1.1> and for second one is <192.168.1.2>. I checked the route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.62.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.237.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
```

But when i ping one from other:

```
ping 192.168.1.2
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

what should i do? My system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just change my approach. In this [tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/AdHoc) the second method is not working. 
In the first method just don't use the "auto wlan0". (If you do you will connect to another network, possibly)

Comment: Do you mean you used the first approach but commented out auto wlan0?.